# I downloaded Ubuntu for the first time and it doesn't install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have 64 bit Windows 7 and 800 GB free space. I downloaded the newest Ubuntu and then when I ran it, it just straight off, without any delay, says can't mount the image.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu ISO is not a windows program and can't run inside windows. Mounting it there probably wouldn't help either. You have to write it to a dvd/usb and boot your computer from it.

See these instructions, complete with pictures, from http://www.ubuntu.com

- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- [Burning ISO How-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)
- [Try Ubuntu before you install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you research how the installation process of an Operating System works. You cant just click the image and expect it to install like a program. You must put it on a USB(via Rufus) or DVD(via Infarecorder) then boot to it, after presume with the installation process.

Infarecorder: http://infrarecorder.org/

Installation process (Works for USB as well, just remember the name of the device, what OS is being used in this wiki is irrelevant):
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-Using-a-CD